# Can't Access System.Data.Entity Namespace Despite Installing Entity Framework v6.1.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've been trying to use the System.Data.Entity namespace in my C# project. From what I understand, I have to install the Entity Framework in order to use it. However, even though I've installed it into my project via NuGet, I still don't see "Data" or "Entity" in the combo box in Visual Studio that appears after "System." Do I need something else to use this namespace? Is the namespace still usable and Visual Studio just doesn't show "Data" or "Entity" in the combo box?

Comment: did you rebuild and does it all compile (try restarting VS if needed, I'm assuming you did) - typically you need to check your target frameworks (e.g. when referencing your own projects) but if you used NuGet that's probably not it - or start sample project from scratch (recreate). Basically you'd need to give us some more info.

Comment: I originally didn't rebuild the project. When I rebuilt it, it worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome Anthony - I've posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

(from a comment - that seems to have answered it)

did you **rebuild** and does it all compile (try restarting VS if needed, I'm assuming you did).

Typically you need to check your target frameworks (e.g. when referencing your own projects) but if you used NuGet that's probably not it.

Or start sample project from scratch (recreate).